# How to get this below layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have 5 pages in signup and I have to add those pages like below image.

Any idea how can I get this below things in android?

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5013 or https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3711

Answer (score 0):

Create two `drawable` (or use two images) for gray and blue oval shapes. Create `View`s and put them in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Use oval shapes as their backgrounds. Between each two ovals, use a `View` with your desired width and 1dp for its height, and set its background attribute to your desired blue color so you can achieve between lines. Then with making correct ones `visible` and other ones `invisible`, add or remove desired lines programmatically. Don't forget to change oval `View`s to correct colors and you'll achieve what you want.